# Cronjob - Unable to find module "pydub"

Tags: python, cron

I have a python script which run perfectly in my Ubuntu 16.04 [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/gcp/). as per the project requirement i have to run this script with crontab (crontab with sudo user)

but when cronjob executed it unable to find python module named "pydub" but this module is installed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/script_path/script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pydub import AudioSegment
ImportError: No module named pydub 

#!/usr/bin/env python3.5
import os
import sys
import magic
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
from pydub import AudioSegment

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk("/var/www/html/files/"):
    for name in files:
        filename = os.path.join(path, name)
        if(filename.find(".mp3") > 0):
            try:
                m = magic.open(magic.MAGIC_MIME)
                m.load()
                mime_type = m.file(filename)
                if(mime_type.find('mpeg') == -1):
                    AudioSegment.from_file(filename).export(filename, format="mp3")
                    print("Converted to MP3")

                f = MP3(filename)
                bitrate = f.info.bitrate / 1000
                if(bitrate > 100):
                    sound = AudioSegment.from_file(filename)
                    sound.export(filename, format="mp3", bitrate="40k")
                    print("Changed the Bitrate!")
            except:
                print(sys.exc_info())
                print(filename)
```

please help

Comment: I have remove screenshot and add code. I am new to python can you please let me know how to get pydub path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try following

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("your installed python module path"))
```

hope this help

---

To get the module path, follow the step:

In the terminal or SSH type

```
 python
```

then type:

```
import pydub
```

then

```
print(pydub)
```

this command will give you module path

Comment: to get module path, follow the step:
in the terminal or SSH type python then
type: import pydub 
then print(pydub)
this command will give you module path